# Encode and Decode ResponseEntity when using Feign and Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to use dynamically feign. But i have many issues when converting the response from RequestMapping.

**Controller.java :**

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> sendUsers
```

**MyFeignClient.java :**

```
public interface MyFeignClient {

@RequestLine(value="GET /api/users")
ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers();}
```

**MainClass.java :**

```
MyFeignClient callService = Feign.builder()
            .encoder(new Encoder.Default())
            .decoder(new Decoder.Default())
            .requestInterceptor(new FeignConfig(props).getJwtRequestInterceptor())
            .target(MyFeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8710");
```

And then :

```
ResponseEntity<List<User>> txnPool = callService.getUsers();
```

But i have the following error :

> feign.codec.DecodeException User is not a type supported by this decoder

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved it by using JacksonEncoder and JacksonDecoder (from the [Netflix Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.feign/feign-jackson) library):

```
MyFeignClient callService = Feign.builder()
        .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
        .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
        .requestInterceptor(new FeignConfig(props).getJwtRequestInterceptor())
        .target(MyFeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8710");
```

i also added `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` to my Feign Interface

Comment: What if the feign client interface `MyFeignClient` is constructor injected? Also, using `eureka` registry we do not run the server in `localhost:8710` ...How would we mention the discovery client name in target folder? How can we add this encode and decode logic in configuration class, if that's possible.