# OpenFeign decode CompletableFuture

Tags: java, jackson, gson, decoder, openfeign

I want to use an async feign client (io.github.openfei and **not** spring-cloud-starter-openfeign) to call my REST Api. Here is my code:

```
interface FeignClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /") CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> hello();
}

FeignClient feignClient = AsyncFeign.builder()
        .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
        .target(FeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8080");

assertEquals("hello", feignClient.hello().get());
```

That is also how it is stated on the official documetion (https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign).

Using **Gson** as decoder, I get the following error

```
 Decode Failed making field 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#result' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
```

I tried to find a TypeAdapter for ComletableFutures but I couldn't find any. I can't believe that there is not such a TypeAdpater and I'm the only one facing the problem.

Using **Jackson** as Decoder, I get another error:

```
Feign Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

I found following related questions on stackoverflow

- [FeignClient could decode response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555237/feignclient-could-decode-response)
- [Encode and Decode ResponseEntity when using Feign and Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384128/encode-and-decode-responseentity-when-using-feign-and-spring-mvc)

but none of these helped.

PS.: The HTTP request works fine using Java HTTP Client.

Comment: Is it good to try to serialize `CompletableFuture` to JSON?

Comment: Please, when also creating a GitHub issue for it **link both to each other** (https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1875). Otherwise people invest their time twice to answer your question.

Comment: It works with Feign >= 12.0

Answer (score 0):

As [discussed in the corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1875#issuecomment-1344860867), this appears to be a bug with Feign which is fixed in version 12.0 and newer.